# Why my admin page not loading a blank page?

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2.4

I generally try and solve problems without soliciting help, but in this case, I'm starting to go around in circles. A lifeline would be appreciated.

I'm installing Mag24 in a VM with Debian10, Apache2.4, PHP 7.4, MariaDB10.4.

For reference, I successfully set up Mag23 in a similar VM. It was not without its challenges, but I was able to work through those. I verified ElasticSearch works. I set up a Magento24 directory under `/var/www`, and changed the owner to mike (with group **www-data**). I use `sudo -u mike bin/magento` to install. After multiple attempts, I'm still getting a blank admin page.

I'm really stuck here, so a lifeline would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps to test it because there are many possible solutions.

## 1 - Check the installation

Let's start running the installation command, you can check the parameters as you need. Even if it's installed you can run it.

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url='https://local.ckurestuff.com/' \
--db-host=db \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=magento \
--db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Le \
--admin-lastname=Site \
--admin-email=rgomes@lesite.ca \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_CA \
--currency=CAD \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--backend-frontname=admin \
--es-hosts=elasticsearch
```

## 2 - Run the system check

```
curl -O https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && \
chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar && \
./n98-magerun2.phar sys:check
```

## 3 - Developer mode

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```